# Кириллица (и другие не-ASCII символы) в тегах чата

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, чат

Есть проблема с отображением кириллических (и, возможно, других, содержащих не-ASCII символы) тегов в обсуждениях, перенесённых из комментариев в чат:

[image]

Кириллические теги отображаются в виде нескольких вопросительных знаков. Проблема не в кодировке - если посмотреть в исходный код страницы, можно увидеть, что текст тега действительно состоит из вопросительных знаков:

[image]

Даже URL тега содержит кучу `%3f` (что является закодированным знаком `?`) и ведёт в никуда.

Несколько примеров:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23200/ (`верстка`)

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23227/ (`ошибка` и `список`)

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23307/ (`база-данных`)

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23314/ (`учебное-задание`)

Я полагаю, что это не баг локализации, а проблема движка чатов Stack Exchange, поэтому изначально я задал этот вопрос на Meta SE, но его перенесли сюда.

Comment: [Аналогичный вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/6/). Обновил задачу в базе дефектов.

Comment: Николай, можете пояснить логику отслеживания подобных ошибок? Почему этому вопросу место именно на Мете русского SO, если потенциально он затрагивает японский и португальский разделы, а также раздел, посвящённый изучению русского языка? Это явно не баг локализации, скорее плохая поддержка Юникода в движке SO.

Comment: Все ошибки локализации отслеживаются сотрудниками интернациональных сообществ. Зачастую, такие ошибки общие для сообществ на всех языках. Например, [не переведенные строки на странице 404](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/66/). Данной строки нет в Transifex, и пока кто-то из сотрудников, занимающихся сообществами на локальных языках не опубликует ее, дело с места не сдвинется. Поскольку ошибку с метками обнаружили пользователи Stack Overflow на русском (то есть вы), то и вопросу место на нашей Мете, а я буду ответственным за отслеживание прогресса (видать, так звезды совпали).

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, учту на будущее.

Comment: судя по сему все еще [актуально](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32095/discussion-between-dmitry-and-bald56rus) была использована метка [архитектура]

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, вопрос всё ещё актуален.

Comment: @LEQADA Спасибо за напоминание! Еще раз обратил внимание ответственных разработчиков на данный дефект.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, [**актуально**](http://pokit.org/get/img/2f0ef820cd2d022006cec5f145172cf0.jpg). Спасибо.

Answer (score 10):

Проблема устранена.

Оказалось, что в базе столбец, хранящий метки комнаты, был типа `varchar` вместо `nvarchar`, поэтому *правильные* метки превращались при сохранении в знаки вопроса. В свою защиту заметим, что эта часть разрабатывалась ещё до того, как о международных сайтах вообще задумывались, и тогда мы разрешили в метках только ASCII-символы.

Я обновил столбец в базе данных, теперь работает как положено.

Comment: Офигенно! (переведите, кто-нибудь)

Comment: @VladD > "Awesome!"

Comment: @VladD Теперь можно делать метки с сердечками. =)

Comment: @Discord: Для вопросов от девушек?